# How to pass an array from app.get() to app.post()

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax

I'm getting an array from ajax file which contain an array of products which I want to add it in the order..I want to link the table of orderProducts & the order table with each other in column called orderId..but I get the array in a app.get() and can't get it in app.post() to post the data..the products is selected in page and the order data is selected in another one.

my ajax code

```
    $('#save').click(function () {
        var orderProduct = new Array();
        $("#review-products input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                      var message0 = row.find('#check').val();
                      var message1 = row.find('.name').text().trim();
                      var message2 =  row.find('.currency').text().trim();
                      var message3 =  row.find(".foo").val();
                      const result =  {check: message0,name: message1,p: message2,q:  message3 ,total: message2 * message3}
                      var hh = orderProduct.push(result);
                });
              $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: {selectedProduct: orderProduct },
                url: '/order/product',
                success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
                }
              })
               })
```

the routes

```
    app.get('/order/product' , getProduct)
    app.post('/postOrder' , postOrder);
    getProduct: (req , res ) => {
      var products = req.query.selectedProduct;
      console.log(products);
    },
    postOrder: (req ,res) => {
      res.redirect('/')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
... 
app.use(bodyParser )

// then
getProduct: (req , res ) => {
  console.log(req.body);
}
```

also change

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    ...
})
```

Comment: I got an empty array in the console!

Comment: Use a console.log( orderProduct  ) before send it. to check the data is available

Comment: I got the data when I click save & move to the add order page but I want to insert it in the same time when I move to the order page

Answer (score 0):

I used global variables to use same variable in both get & post functions